# Odd Compiler Error in C++ (VC compiler)

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compiler-errors, floating-point, typechecking

For this code,

```
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    float x = 1.5f;
    float y = 0.0f;
/*line6*/   y = pow(x, 6) * 235809835.41 - pow(x, 5) * 2110439254.2 + pow(x, 4) *7869448124.8 - pow(x, 3) * 15648965509 + pow(x, 2) * 17503313074 - (x)* 10440563329 + 2594694745‏; // error
/*line7*/   y = pow(x, 6) * 235809835.41 - pow(x, 5) * 2110439254.2 + pow(x, 4) *7869448124.8 - pow(x, 3) * 15648965509 + pow(x, 2) * 17503313074 - (x)* 10440563329 + 2594694745;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error log -

```
maincpp.cpp(6) : warning C4244 : '=' : conversion from 'double' to 'float', possible loss of data
maincpp.cpp(6) : error C2146 : syntax error : missing ';' before identifier '‏'
maincpp.cpp(6) : error C2065 : '‏' : undeclared identifier
```

Line 6 fails to compile. What I find most astonishing is that line 7 compiles even though it is identical to line 6. So, if I comment out line 6 and retain line 7, then the program compiles successfully.

I am on Windows 8 64 bit, and this program was written in Visual Studio 2013 as a Win 32 Console Application.

In production code, I would terminate all float literals with f. But in any case, I don't expect a compiler error without it.

The equation was generated in Excel.

Comment: Can we see the full code ? (from 1 to 7) ?

Comment: @jd6, all the lines are there - 1 to 7

Comment: Sorry for my negligence.

Comment: Your source code is mangled, it contains an unprintable Unicode character between the 5 and the ; on line 6, U+200F.  It is the Right-to-Left Mark formatting character.  You can't see it, although the "'‏' : undeclared identifier" error message is a pretty good hint, the compiler however sees it and complains.  Watch out copy/pasting code from a web site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looks like you have a stray [right-to-left mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) in Line 6 before the semicolon:

```
... 2594694745<U+200F>;
```

Comment: Copied into Vim; sure enough, this is the reason. Hell of a catch.